# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json

I'm teaching myself AJAX to AJAXify my site. In my template, I have the following JS code to get some JSON data from a view then append the data to a div.

```
function filter(type) {
  $.getJSON(
    '/activity_stream/global-activity-stream/', 
    {xhr: "true", filter: type}, 
    function(data) {
      $('.mainContent').children().remove();
      $(data).appendTo('.mainContent');
    });
  }

  $(".btn").click(function () { 
    filter("recent"); 
  });
}
```

I think my view is returning proper JSON but now data is not being added to the `.mainContent` div.

It gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined.

Comment: If you're getting JSON back, then just appending it into the DOM isn't going to work. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I guess i expected it to load the data into the div...How can i achieve this? Am new to this AJAXy stuff...

Comment: Just change `$('.mainContent').children().remove();    $(data).appendTo('.mainContent');` to `$('.mainContent').html(data);` The problem is, when you do `appendTo`, jquery expects the `$(data)` to be a dom node, which it is most likely not in this case

Comment: Thanks,that helped with that error though now the returned JSON data aint being displayed in the div :-(

Comment: @karthikr that's just going to dump the raw JSON onto the page, but yes `$('.mainContent').html(data);` should show whatever came from the server (as just raw JSON text). (No need to remove the children before doing that.) You can use the browser debugging tools to check and see exactly what the server is returning.

Comment: @Pointy - That is exactly what the OP is intending to do anyways. I agree JSON would have to be parsed

Comment: OP should look into JS templating.  Underscore.js has an easy template system where you create the tmpl, pass in the json obj, and then add that to the DOM

Answer (score 52):

Make sure you're passing a selector to jQuery, not some form of data:

```
$( '.my-selector' )
```

not:

```
$( [ 'my-data' ] )
```

Comment: This was spot on for me. I thought the issue was with my jQuery functions but actually I was an array as opposed to my usual single obj. Thanks man

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue.
I was using jQuery.map but I forgot to use jQuery.map(...).get() at the end to work with a normal array.

Answer (score 4):

The same issue came up for me inside of `$elms.each()`.

Because:

1. the function you pass to `.each(Function)` exposes (at least) two arguments; the first being the index and the second being the element in the current element in the list, and
2. because other similar looping methods give current the element in the array before the index

you may be tempted to do this:

```
$elms.each((item) => $(item).addClass('wrong'));
```

When this is what you need:

```
$elms.each((index, item) => $(item).addClass('wrong'));
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are appending to the DOM, make sure the content is compatible:

```
modal.find ('div.modal-body').append (content) // check content
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use ES6 anon functions, it will conflict with `$(this)`

This works:

```
$('.dna-list').on('click', '.card', function(e) {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
$('.dna-list').on('click', '.card', (e) => {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: My situation, this was the correct answer. I keep forgetting that arrow functions bind their `this` to the closest regular function's `this`.

Comment: If it is triggering, use the event like `e.currentTarget` or maybe it's `$(e.currentTarget)`. It should work the same as this while still allowing anon functions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error happened because my HTML had a trailing linebreak.

```
var myHtml = '<p>\
    This should work.\
    But does not.\
</p>\
';

jQuery('.something').append(myHtml); // this causes the error
```

To avoid the error, you just need to trim the HTML.

```
jQuery('.something').append(jQuery.trim(myHtml)); // this works
```