# Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null - JQuery AJAX error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I'm having this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var userInput = $("#userInput").val();
$.ajax({
   url: 'foodstore.php',
   data: userInput,
   method: 'GET',
   success: function(response){
       $("#underInput").html(response);
   }
});
 });
```

php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
$food = $_GET['food'];
$foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','beef','ham');
if(in_array($food,$foodArray)){
    echo 'We do have '.$food.'!';
}elseif ($food==''){
    echo 'Enter a food you idiot';
}else{
    echo 'Sorry punk we dont sell no '.$food.'!';
}
echo '</response>';

?>
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="foodstore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
        Enter the food you would like to order:
        <input type="text" id="userInput" />
        <div id="underInput" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And when I try to run it I get an error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
I know I am missing something, but I don't know what.
I am learning JQuery and it's a little blurry to me.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594855/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-ownerdocument-of-undefined

Comment: I saw it and i still don't get it

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the error, but it should be `data: { food: userInput}`

Comment: `<div>` is not a self-closing tag, you can't use `<div id="underInput"/>`. It shouldbe `<div id="underInput"></div>`

Comment: Why are you returning XML instead of HTML?

Comment: Go up in the stack trace until you get to your code. Which line of the code is it failing on?